# Optimise httpd/mysql for battery life

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, battery

this is a bit of a weird one.

Basically, I'm going to be on a 12 hour flight soon, and I'd like to know if I could tune Apache2 and MySQL 5.1 to use less CPU/RAM and thus less energy so I can conserve battery life for the flight? Performance-wise... I frankly don't care if it suffers, because I'll be working locally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do anything specifically for MySQL and Apache as far as configuration. Step the processor down do a lower speed as well as dim the screen. I think that will buy you more time than trying to tweak your configs. As long as MySQL is idle most of the time and not consuming the CPU you should be ok. Try to minimize intensive queries and web operations to conserve CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing overall disk access with caches or solid state options (e.g. USB memory sticks) can also yield some additional battery run time as well.